# How to efficiently sum numpy arrays after multiply them?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numpy, addition, multiplication

Actually I need to compute:

```
S_i = sum(U_j * U_j.transpose) * K_i
```

where

```
U_j is a n * k dim matrix, 
K_i is a n * n dim matrix, 
j != i, 
i = 1, 2, ..., n
```

And I used loops like this:

```
import numpy as np
for i in xrange(n):
    temp = np.zeros((n, n))
    for j in xrange (n):
        if j != i:
            temp += np.dot(U[j], U[j].T)
    S[i] = np.dot(temp, K[i])
```

Is there any more efficient method to do this?

Comment: `for j in xrange (n) and j != i` should have raised a SyntaxError. Did you mean to break that up into a `for-loop` and an `if-statement`?

Comment: @unutbu yes you are right, what I mean to do is `for j in xrange(n):    if j != i:` but I made a mistake on syntax and I wonder is there a better way to do this~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

n, k = 30, 40

U = np.random.random((n, n, k))
K = np.random.random((n, n, n))

def using_loops(U, K):
    S = np.empty((n, n, n))
    for i in xrange(n):
        temp = np.zeros((n, n))
        for j in xrange (n):
            if j != i:
                temp += np.dot(U[j], U[j].T)
        S[i] = np.dot(temp, K[i])
    return S

def using_einsum(U, K):
    uut = np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl', U, U)
    total = uut.sum(axis=0)
    total = total - uut
    S = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', total, K)
    return S
```

This tests that `using_loops` and `using_einsum` produce the same result.

```
In [260]: np.allclose(using_loops(U, K), using_einsum(U, K))
Out[260]: True
```

This shows using_einsum is faster; how much faster depends on the size of `n` and `k`:

```
In [262]: %timeit using_loops(U, K)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop

In [263]: %timeit using_einsum(U, K)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.92 ms per loop
```

---

In general, whenever you see sums of products, there is a good chance that
[np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum)
will be a fairly fast way to produce the result. It will almost surely beat
Python for-loops.

Comment: I've read the documentation of usage of 'np.einsum', but I'm quite confused about the parameter 'operands'. The last example is `np.einsum('ki,jk->ij', a, b)`, which I think equals to `np.dot(a.T, b.T)` if I'm not wrong. But why the operand is `ki, jk->ij` other than `ji, kj->ik` ? If only you could explain it for me~ thx~~

Comment: And what if the formula **S_i = sum(U_j * U_j.transpose) * K_i** where i is not necessarily equals to n but far less than n, is there any change on the difference of time efficiency between using `np.dot` and `np.einsum` ?

Comment: About operands in `numpy.einsum`, I figured it out ~ thank you~ :)

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the subscript notation in `np.einsum` -- it takes some getting used to. For the second question, do you mean you only wish to compute `S_i` for a few values (or a single value) of `i` much less than `n`?

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I mean~ Under such circumstance, what about the efficiency using `np.dot` and `np.einsum`~?

Comment: If you only want to compute `S_i` for one value of `i`, then I have not found a way to do it faster than with one for-loop.